# resizing an element with jscrollpane

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, responsive-design

I have a site with an area that needs to resize as the window resizes (and the way this site will be used, I think people will be resizing the window frequently).  This by itself isn't a problem.  I have this HTML and CSS:

```
<body>
<header>
  stuff
</header>
<article class="scroll">
  lots of stuff
</article>
<footer>
  stuff
</footer>
</body>

article {
position: fixed;
top: 180px;
left: 30px;
bottom: 60px;
right: 30px;
overflow: auto;
}
```

This works just fine, and the article resizes as the window resizes.

But then I added jscrollpane to the article so that it would have a pretty scrollbar.  Now, when you resize the window, the article does not resize with it - the article stays the size that it was in your original window.  If you hit refresh, it will resize appropriately, but that's lame.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7cMvy/

Any suggestions?

Comment: Would you add your code in http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Answer (score 2):

you resolve your problem repeating the activation instructions detecting window resize event function as in this example.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $(function(){
        $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({
                showArrows: true,
                horizontalGutter: 30,
                verticalGutter: 30,
                arrowScrollOnHover: true
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Michele